# Strange results with in Oracle Apex using Pivot showing nulls and n

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot, oracle-apex

Im running a oracle 11g with Apex 4.2.6. Im trying to run a script but giving back nulls in apex but showing correct results in SQL developer

```
  select "ENG_ID","ENG_ID1","roles","Region","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"    ,"16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31" from (
   select M.ENG_ID as ENG_ID,
M.ENG_ID as ENG_ID1,
e.ROLE_ID as "roles",
  e.REGION_AREA_ID as "Region",
EXTRACT(DAY FROM M.MS_DATE) as DOM,
   MD.MD_ID 
      --MD.JOB_TYPE_ID
from MD_TS_DETAIL MD,
MD_TS_MAST M,MAN_ENGINEERS e
where
m.eng_id = 542 and
M.ENG_ID = e.ENG_ID and
M.MAST_ID=MD.MD_ID and
M.MS_DATE between trunc(sysdate,'MM') and last_day(sysdate)
)pivot (
max(MD_ID) 
for DOM in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31)
)
```

which gives me the correct result of

[image] SQL Dev view

Yet running the same script within Apex you get nulls.

[image] apex view.

I'm completely stumped do you guys have any ideas

Comment: I think im on to something but still stumped, I ran select 
max(MAST_ID)
 from MD_TS_MAST
 on the database directly and got 90367. running the same script in APEX I got 69738

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after checking what the max records where both records where both on APEX and the database directly. 
. In SQL workshop > selected MD_TS_MAST > statistics > analyse > estimate statistics change to 100% > next >finish.

all records came back. Why apex did not run from the database directly I don't know. So basicily if doing  inserts in SQL developer, You must do a update via analyse.

Comment: As I know, APEX run directly from the database. If you did inserts in IDE, maybe you just forgot to commit? Otherwise, I don't know how to explain that.